# Conditional join in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, database-design

I have a Postgres table log_actions with fields:

**id** - id of the action
**userId**
**action** - BAN, ADD_PROCESS, etc...
**action_id**

action_id is the id from one of the following tables: 
**user_bans** for action=BAN
**user_processes** for action=ADD_PROCESS

1. My first question is it ok to have such kind of architecture. I mean action_id field which contains id to different tables.
2. If it is then I would appreciate any help how to conditionally join log_actions, user_bans, user_processes. I read the documentation but didn't realize how to do it.
   Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I'd advise against such a design, because it precludes the use of foreign keys for integrity control. (You may want to look into entity subclassing.) It also looks as if you have a normalisation issue in that `action_id` seems to functionally determine `action` without being a superkey.

Answer (score 1):

This is a viable structure for handling "one-of" relationships.  As Jon points out, you cannot declare foreign key relationships.  That is a shame, so this is not a great solution.

Postgres offers table inheritance.  This probably does exactly what you want.  The "action" tables can all inherit `actionid` from an `actions` table.  This can be used for the join.  Each table can then have its own specific columns (and foreign key relationships).

Refer to the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-inherit.html) for more information about inheritance.

Comment: That table inheritance is a bit interesting, but from the example I don't really see what benefits it offers compared to doing it "manually", considering its drawbacks. Do you have experience with it?

Comment: @JonHeggland . . . One advantage over "doing it manually" is that you can have properly declared foreign key relationships.

Comment: Seems like the other way around to me. The manual approach—`cities{name,population,altitude}`, `capitals{name,state}`, foreign key from capitals to cities (assuming `{name}`as key)—has none of the caveats listed in 5.9.1, and can be implemented with standard SQL to boot.